# Excel: How do you add a number to each cell in a range then multiply them together?

Tags: microsoft-excel, spreadsheet, google-spreadsheets

Let's say I have the following values in cells:

```
    A     B     C     D
1  0.1 | 0.5 | 0.3 | 2.1`
```

I am looking for the formula with which I can calculate *without intermediate cells*

```
(1 + 0.1) * (1 + 0.5) * (1 + 0.3) * (1 + 2.1)
```

What I've tried was (without success):

```
PRODUCT(1 + A1:D1)
```

Comment: Your formula will work if it is entered as an array formula.  Confirm the formula with Ctrl-Shift-Enter instead of Enter when leaving edit mode.  If done correctly then excel will put `{}` around the formula.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all thank you for the comments @Scott / @Marcin

The correct answer would then be:

In **Google Sheets**:

```
=PRODUCT(ARRAYFORMULA(A1:D1 + 1))
```

In **Excel** you have to finish your command with `Ctrl + Shift + Enter` or `Cmd + Shift + Enter` to get the correct result. The resulting field value will be

```
{=PRODUCT(A1:D1 + 1)}
```

Note: The `{}` cannot be entered manually.

Comment: could you explain the downvote? This actually has been the full answer that I would have been looking for.

Answer (score 2):

(tried just commenting, but don't have enough rep in this community)

@Scott is correct, and make sure to spell the function name correctly - your post has a typo, missing `U` in `PRODUCT(...)`.